# Show special symbol for each series in category in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to draw chart that is looks like below
[image]

So far so I have achieved what you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdzzdLeh/1/).

I want to know :-

1 . How can I place special symbol(diamond) with each series in each category ?

2. Is there anything better than what I have done ?

**Relevant Code**

```
series: [{
                           name: 'Meeting 1',
                           data: [
                                     {y:100,color:'#F4B183'},
                                     {y:100,color:'#FFE699'},
                                     {y:100,color:'#FFD966'},
                                  ]
                          }, 
                          {
                              name: 'Meeting 2',

                              data: [
                                      {y:100,color:'#F4B183'},
                                      {y:100,color:'#FFE699'},
                                      {y:100,color:'#FFD966'}
                                    ]
                          }, 
                          {
                              name: 'Meeting 3',
                              data: [
                                      {y:100,color:'#F4B183'},
                                      {y:100,color:'#FFE699'},
                                      {y:100,color:'#FFD966'} 
                                    ]
                          }
                       ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extra scatter serie with [diamond marker](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.marker.symbol)

```
            {
                type:'scatter',
                color:'black',
                marker:{
                    symbol:'diamond'
                },
                data:[[2,50]]
            }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/mdzzdLeh/3/

Alternative solution: use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path).